# ExtJS rowediting beforeedit Ajax call

Tags: extjs

I'm using the rowediting plugin and have a beforeedit listener.  I need to find a way to make an Ext.Ajax.request in my beforeedit function to determine if the row should be locked or not.  The reason is to make sure some other user isn't already editing a particular row.  If I find the row should be locked I would return false.

Anything I've tried with defer hasn't stopped the function from completing and essentially returning true.  Ext.Promise looks like what I might need, but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First disable how ExtJS starts row editing by default. Where you define your grid, within the `plugins` part, add this:

```
plugins: [{
  ptype: 'rowediting',
  onCellClick: function(view, cell, colIdx, record, row, rowIdx, e) {
    return; // this will disable starting row editor on click
  } 
}]
```

Then add a custom handler to start row editing, make the Ajax call there, and only start editing if the row is editable by your logic. For example you can add an action column with edit icon:

```
columns: [{
// add the other columns
},{
  xtype: 'actioncolumn',
  width: 40,
  items: [{
    iconCls: ...,
    tooltip: ...,
    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
      const plugin =  grid.grid.getPlugin('rowEditing');
      // mask the grid for the time of the Ajax call
      grid.mask('Please, wait...');
      Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: ...,
        success: function(response, opts) {
          grid.unmask();
          // if it is ok to edit according to the response
          if (...) {
             plugin.startEdit(rowIndex);
          }
        },
        failure: function(response, opts) {
          grid.unmask();
        },
    }
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.